# Do I need the source code of the app to get performance metrics using Instruments?

Tags: ios, performance, instruments

I am interested in evaluating performance to an external iOS app. Can I use instruments only with binaries?

Is also around non-apple tools to do this?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Instruments with your device and attach it to any running process.

Launch the app yourself and then attach to it from the Attach to Process... command in the Target menu in the Instruments window